# Decompile WP7 xap file from market

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace, xap

How can I decompile *.xap file downloaded from WP7 marketplace?

For example this one:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/camper/b0e9a2f4-243d-47db-b61e-0ea16847c25a

Answer (score 1):

A xap is a zip file. Extract its contents using a program like 7zip and then use a standard .NET decompiler (like ILSpy or Reflector) on the contained dlls.

Comment: Have you tried this? provided app can't be extracted by 7zip :(

Comment: Not with your specific app, but with others, yes. A xap file is definitely a zip file. And using 7zip > Open Archive on a xap file should display its contained assemblies

Comment: Marketplace XAPs are DRM signed and cannot be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Also xap is definitely a zip file. Rename the extension of the file and open with any zip utility. Windows directly opens zip file, just rename the extension. Then use any decompiler, I personally like Telerik's just-decompile(free).

But please clarify, how do you (or anyone) gets the xap file form marketplace.

Comment: I'm just downloading it from the marketplace using browser. And it can't be opened by 7zip

Comment: Marketplace XAPs are DRM signed and cannot be opened.

Comment: Yes, I checked that after posting the solution. At that time I was not aware that Microsoft has added an option to download XAP's (I think this feature was started after release of WP8). I wasn't able to open those files in a zip program.